# Put value in checkbox ASP.NET Control?

Tags: repeater, webforms, checkbox

i am a newbie programmer in ASP.NET. So My database have two tables: `UserTypes and UserTypeDivisions`

```
UserType contains for example
UserTypeId        Description
     1             Programmer
     2              Designer

UserTypeDivisions contains for example
UserTypeDivisionId     UserTypeId     Description
     1                     1              c#
     2                     1              Ruby
     3                     1              c++
     4                     2              Web  
     5                     2              Books
```

Then i have a table for tutorials. Each tutorial can be accessed by all divisions or only for some. So i want print userTypes and its Divisions with `checkboxes`.

My problem is thar i use two repeater with checkboxes asp NEt . But i don´t know how assign value attribute to checkboxes (userTypeDivisionId).

How could i assign to checkbox ASP.NEt control the value attribute?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using webforms I would go use a checkboxlist, rather than a repeater with checkboxes. you can then define the text and value properties of the check box list.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the checked value of it with a databound value in your repeater's ItemTemplate